# Test if device is on the same layer 2 switch from command line

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, ping

In a nutshell, what I'm looking for is a variation of `ping 10.0.0.24` that, in this example network, would only work when the laptop is placed in the GREEN position. If the same laptop is moved to the BLUE or RED position, the same command should fail.

[image]

So far, I've only come up with two commands that fail in the RED position. They still succeeds in the BLUE position.

```
C:\> ping -i 1 10.0.0.24 && echo SUCCESS || echo FAIL
C:\> ping -r 10.0.0.24 | find "Route: 10.0.0.24" && echo SUCCESS || echo FAIL
```

I know some of you will be questioning why I would want this. My answer is:

> I use Acronis to save backups of my laptop to the NAS. My laptop is subject to move around the network. So, I'm using this as a pre-command in the backup options to prevent it from running if the traffic is going to go through any of the switches or routers.

That being said, I'm certainly open to alternative ideas for accomplishing that, but not as answers to this question. I'd still like to find a command that only works in the GREEN position.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy/generic way to do this without a network change as the switches are invisible to the network stack.

Depending on your workload / flexibility / network requirements / network level, consider getting a cheap router and then inserting it between the green position and the switch - then look at the IP address the computer has to determine its location.  This may require tweeking/not work well if the NAS requires to see devices directly to be work - but this is likely the easiest obstacle to overcome.

It's unlikely to work well, but depending on what's been deployed, you MUGHT be able to ascertain different ping characteristics (eg latency) to the NAS from different points in the network and use that to determine location.

Depending on the functionality of the layer 3 switch closest to the green port, you may be put a rule in place to prevent it having access to something else, then ping that and rely on a failure (or have it block access to the NAS - but I expect the later will be undesirable as it will make the NAS unaccessible to parts of the network.